# When and where to declare @property? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes its done in the header file, sometimes its done in the implementation. I'm fairly new to programming. Could someone briefly explain when to do which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it's meant for other classes, put it in the header. When it's just meant for that class, put it in a class extension in the implementation file.

Comment: But if it's just meant for that class, wouldn't you just declare it as a class method?

Comment: No. Class methods are methods the class itself implements, rather than being implemented by instances of the class. Particularly in the case of properties, each instance has its own distinct instance variable/property values, and so the accessor _must_ be instance methods. Declaring the @properties in a class extension simply makes it so that code in other source files can't "see" the properties and causes the compiler to emit a warning when you try to access them outside the class's implementation. It's a way of implementing information hiding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding.